# Locking Physics Body to X Axis Spritekit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a node that I would like to lock to the x axis. I have an impulse on the node (shown below).

```
    rectangle.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(-11,0))
```

The node starts off on the x axis, but as soon as it makes contact with another physics body, it flies off on the y axis as well as the x. I would like to know how to lock it to the x axis so it cannot move up or down. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can constrain the _y_ position of a node with https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKConstraint_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKConstraint/positionY:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could lock the movement in the update function for the node if you create a SKNode/SKSpriteNode etc. subclass.

This way you always lock the movement to the axis you want. You wouldnt lock the physics body, but the node itself.

> Update

You will need to store the point of the node as the collision occurs, using the collision delegates.

e.g. collisionPoint = node.center

You can lock its position to an axis like this

```
func update(dt: NSTimeInterval)
{
    // locks the position to collision points y coordintate
    self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x, collisionPoint.y) 
}
```

call this update function from the scene's

> override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)

Comment: Thanks, but what code would I write to make this happen? @Helium3